# Quiero aprender a programar

Tags: python-3.x

esta es mi primera; Quiero aprender a programar pero debido a cuestiones económicas he optado por ser autodidacta, tengo conocimiento básico sobre el uso del ordenador y nulo sobre programación, como podría empezar y mirar si esto es realmente para mi. Gracias

Comment: Muchachos, por favor, eviten dar negativos a los usuarios que tienen 1 punto, recién están empezando en el sitio. Gracias por su comprensión.

Comment: Bienvenido, te comento que tu pregunta es basada en opiniones y por ese motivo terminaría cerrada, te invito a que hagas el [tour] y cheques [ask]

Comment: Saludos Sebastian, como dice el buen @Aprendiz, revisa los enlaces que te acaba de compartir, por otro lado, http://www.tutorialesprogramacionya.com/ aquí tienes muy buenos tutoriales en español. de python y otras tecnologías. Te sugiero (y te obligaría si pudiera) a que aprendas inglés (y si ya lo sabes, que lo mejores), te recomiendo la adquisición del idioma puesto que te abrirá muchas oportunidades. Conforme aprendas las estructuras básicas de un lenguaje de programación, desarrolla tu lógica aquí: https://www.codewars.com/ cuando tengas tu cuenta, en Clan, coloca "SOes". Bienvenido :D

Comment: Olvidé mencionar los recursos para el idioma inglés: Duolingo, Memrise, engvid.com, en youtube: canal inglés 1 2 3. Usa la app "Tandem" para conversar con gente que quiere aprender español y que quiera enseñar inglés.

Comment: @Aprendiz gracias bro, hay que formar buenos usuarios, entre todos sí podemos :D

Comment: @fredyfx Hay que buscar un equilibrio. No es bueno coser a negativos a los usuarios nuevos que están haciendo una pregunta que no se ajusta al formato del sitio, es mejor dejar un comentario explicando los problemas y enlazando a recursos... Pero tampoco es bueno que una pregunta de baja calidad que no se ajusta bien al formato del sitio tenga un +3.